# Change to language on flag click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have some flag icons and I want my site to change to that specified language when clicked on that flag. How can I improve this code? How can I distinguish each id inside the  tags?

I also thought of using states but I'm not quite sure how...

```
const Header = () => {
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    const lang = i18n.language;

    const onLanguageChangeBR = (lang) => {
        i18n.changeLanguage("pt");
    }
    const onLanguageChangeEN = (lang) => {
        i18n.changeLanguage("en");
    }
    const onLanguageChangeFR = (lang) => {
        i18n.changeLanguage("fr");
    }
    const onLanguageChangeES = (lang) => {
        i18n.changeLanguage("es");
    }

    return(
        <header>
            <div className="header__bg"> </div> 
                <div className="container header__container">
                    <h5>{t("greetings")}</h5>
                    <h1>{t("name")}</h1>
                    <h5 className="text-light">{t("course")}</h5>
                    <CTA />
                    <HeaderSocials />

                    <div className="page__idiom">
                        <a href="#" onClick={onLanguageChangeBR} id="flag__br"> 
                            <ReactCountryFlag className="flag__attributes" countryCode="BR" svg />
                        </a>

                        <a href="#" onClick={onLanguageChangeEN} id="flag__en">
                            <ReactCountryFlag className="flag__attributes" countryCode="US" svg />
                        </a>

                        <a href="#" onClick={onLanguageChangeFR} id="flag__fr">
                            <ReactCountryFlag className="flag__attributes" countryCode="FR" svg />
                        </a>

                        <a href="#" onClick={onLanguageChangeES} id="flag__es">
                            <ReactCountryFlag className="flag__attributes" countryCode="ES" svg />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="language__dropdown">
                    <img src="" alt="" />
                </div>
        </header>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

first of, try not to repeat yourself and simplify your code. instead of writing a new method for each language pass the code as an argument

```
const onLanguageChange = (langCode) => {
        i18n.changeLanguage(langCode);
    }
```

and then in markup

```
<a href="#" onClick={ () => onLanguageChange('pt') } id="flag__br"> 
                            <ReactCountryFlag className="flag__attributes" countryCode="BR" svg />
                        </a>

                        <a href="#" onClick={ () => onLanguageChange('en') } id="flag__en">
                            <ReactCountryFlag className="flag__attributes" countryCode="US" svg />
                        </a>
```

state is what makes the web go round. in react its nice to use the useState hook for your component state. e.g.

```
let [ state, useState ] = useState('initialValue')
```

state variable has the latest state value, which you use in your component and you set a new value with setState('newValue') and when it changes, react will rerender dependants and nested components